# How can i prevent my keyboard from hiding my widgets in a ScrollableView

Tags: flutter, dart

Am implementing this plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) and in the **body** i create a screen that uses `SingleChildScrollView` to show some **text fields**,
Like the documentation says

> **Body**: The Widget that lies underneath the sliding panel. This Widget
> automatically sizes itself to fill the screen.

The problem is that when I give *focus* to one of the **text fields** the keyboard *appears* and *hides* what I am writing,

I use the plugin passing a the widget i want to show behind

```js
SlidingUpPanel(
...
 body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 160 + padding!.top),
        child: behindWidget,
      ),
...
)
```

[image]

then this

[image]

I was trying to enclose my `SingleChildScrollView` inside a `scaffold` to use this: `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true`, but that doesn't seem to make any difference, does anyone have any idea what I can do? and if there is a way to do it directly from the `TextFormField` would it be better?

I also have to say that I am using a `DefaultTabController` and in the first tab I enclose my `SingleChildScrollView`

like this:

```js
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        child: DefaultTabController(
          initialIndex: 0,
          length: myTabs.length,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              bottom: TabBar(
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                labelStyle: smallTextBoldBlack,
                unselectedLabelColor: unselectedColor,
                unselectedLabelStyle: smallTextUnselectedSecondary,
                indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                controller: _tabController,
                tabs: myTabs,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Create a new Event',
                style: subTitle,
              ),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
              controller: _tabController,
              children: [
                _buildCreateEventView(),
                Text("b"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

> _buildCreateEventView()

```js
  Widget _buildCreateEventView() {
    return ExpandableCalendar(
        eventList: [],
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        onDateSelected: (DateTime selectedDate) => {
              if (this.mounted)
                setState(() {
                  currentDate = selectedDate;
                })
            },
        behindWidget: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 10),
            color: Colors.white,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 5),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: eventNameController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Enter Event Summary',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 5),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: eventDescriptionController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Enter Event Description',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add One more Container inside SingleChildScrollView and remove Scaffold

```
    Container
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
         SingleChildScrollView
            Container
               ConstrainedBox
```

Comment: it still doesn't work just the keyboard appears and covers everything :/

Comment: @theboshy Problem with Scaffold hierarchy remove Scaffold from  _buildCreateEventView

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your ExpandableCalendar class works but I suspect it's what is preventing Flutter from resizing the Scaffold body to move the text fields above the keyboard. If you try temporarily removing ExpandableCalendar and you see the widgets moving above your keyboard that should give you a clue to the underlying issue.

Comment: ExpandableCalendar is just an implementation of this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel, no matter what I put on the **body**, the keyboard always hide it